# How to put images into an array Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, for-loop, each

I have a Ruby on Rails app that allows a user to save up to 6 images that can then be viewed in a carousel.

The images are saved as strings as image, image_2, image_3, image_4, image_5, image_6.

I want to be able to write a 'for' loop to display all of the images in my carousel.

What is the best method of combining all of these image strings into an array so that they can then be looped through and outputted by the carousel?

**Further Details**

I am currently calling the images like below which works but isn't particularly DRY.

```
<div style="position:relative">
  <div id="home-carousel" class="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">

      <div class="item active">
        <%= image_tag @place.image %>
      </div>

      <% if @place.image_2.present? %>
        <div class="item">
          <%= image_tag @place.image_2 %>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <% if @place.image_3.present? %>
        <div class="item">
          <%= image_tag @place.image_3 %>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <% if @place.image_4.present? %>
        <div class="item">
          <%= image_tag @place.image_4 %>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <% if @place.image_5.present? %>
        <div class="item">
          <%= image_tag @place.image_5 %>
        </div> 
      <% end %>

      <% if @place.image_6.present? %>  
        <div class="item">
          <%= image_tag @place.image_6 %>
        </div>
      <% end %>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to be able to turn what I have below into a simple for loop that will go through each of the 6 image objects and return the ones that are there. Something more like this:

```
<div style="position:relative">
  <div id="home-carousel" class="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <% @place.images.each do |image| %>
        <div class="item">
          <%= image_tag image %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show us the context and what you tried

Comment: When you mention image "strings", what do you mean? You mean their localized paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is to add a helper. So in `helpers/places_helper.rb` write

```
module PlacesHelper

  def get_carrousel_images(place)
    [
      @place.image_1,
      @place.image_2,
      @place.image_3,
      @place.image_4,
      @place.image_5,
      @place.image_6
    ].select {|img| img.present? }
  end
```

and then you can write the following in your view:

```
<div style="position:relative">
  <div id="home-carousel" class="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <% get_carrousel_images(@place).each do |image| %>
        <div class="item">
          <%= image_tag image %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now having the 6 `image_x` fields for place looks a bit smelly, so I would prefer a nested model instead as Rich Peck proposes, although I understand having the 6 fields is easier to start with.

Comment: Thanks for your help Nathanvda this seems to work so long as there are always 6 images. When it's missing images it's returning 'src="/assets"' which is meaning no images at all are displayed. Any ideas how I can handle if an image object is blank?

Comment: I do the `compact`, which should delete the nils. If there is no image, is the `image_x` nil or an empty string?

Comment: Ah my bad, they are coming through as nils and it is deleting them where they don't exist. Seems to be working now :)

Comment: Oh no. It's broken again. It's passing back a src="assets".

Comment: You do have to give me a little more info. Code does not simply work and then not work. Can you find out what the difference is? When does it work, when doesn't it? But assuming the code you gave us always worked, I am assuming some do have empty string instead of nil, so I replaced the `compact` with a `select` which mimics your above code.

Answer (score 0):

**Images**

It will all depend on how you've set up the `images` in the db, and how you'd like to show them in the view

If you have the images in the `User` model, you could call them like this:

```
app/controllers/users_controller.rb
Class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def show
       @user = User.find params[:id]
       @images = @user.images
   end
end
```

This is obviously very generalised - I would recommend you post some context to your question, so we know what you're asking specifically

--

**Paperclip**

If you're using [`Paperclip`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) or [`Carrierwave`](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave), you'll basically have the images attached to various objects in your database. For example, you'll have the following:

```
#app/models/image.rb
Class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_attached_file :attachment
end
```

This allows you to call:

```
@images = Image.all
@images.each do |image|
   image.attachment.url #-> image URL
end
```

This is the standard way to handle images / attachments in Rails, as it ties directly into `ActiveRecord`. Returning an array of `image` paths would therefore be a case of calling `Model.all` or `Model.where`

Comment: Thanks for your reply Rich! I have added some further explanation above. Images in this instance are saved on the Place model using the carrierwave gem. Hopefully my extra info above will make things a little more clear :)